# stylize input select [options next to options]

Tags: html, css

I tried to style `HTML` code with `CSS`. 
I need to style this to something like toggle switch for checkbox. 
Unfortunately need stay with input type select.

This is posible or I must change to checkbox and should stylize it ? 
I've never used `CSS` before and I don't know where to start. Current code:

**CSS:**

```
<style>

input[type=submit] {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


label, input[type=submit] {
display: block;
}
div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
```

**HTML;**

```
<h3>Using CSS to style an HTML Form</h3>

<div>
  <form>
    <label for="decision">decision</label>
    <select id="decision" name="decision">
      <option value="true">true</option>
      <option value="false">false</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: My suggestion would be search the internet for creating a toggle switch, I'd suggest using [bootstrap switch](http://bootstrapswitch.com/), if you are not familiar with bootstrap go for learning bootstrap online! Refer this online [series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqOEoUR5RHg)

Comment: I can't add eny external css/js librarys.  I can base only on standard elemnts.
side-by-side horizontal - yes

Comment: @JJanek how about a simple site that generates the site for you! [here](https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/)

Comment: Ok but this is base on the checkobox but I trying stylize select -> options :)
Without ingerent to the HTML or JS - I can change only CSS

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can target different elements via (among others) tagname/class/id. 
In your case I would suggest just targeting your select-element via id by doing:

```
#decision {
    /* style goes here */
}
```

Here you can use whatever styling that is compatible with the select-element.

I suggest you take a look at [a guide for selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), to give you an idea on how to continue. 
Good luck!